# Calling endEditing from viewWill/DidDisappear

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a keyboard toolbar that isn't being hidden properly. If the user hits the Done button, I call the following code:

```
- (void)accessoryDoneAction:(id)sender {
    [self.selectedAmount endEditing:YES];
}
```

Then if the user moves to the next screen, comes back, locks the phone and unlocks it everything is fine. However, if the user does not hit the Done button, and moves on to the next view, comes back, locks the phone and unlocks the phone, they will see the keyboard toolbar at the bottom of the screen.

The only difference between the two scenarios, that I can see, is that if the user does not hit the done button, `endEditing` isn't called until `viewWillDisappear:` or `viewDidDisappear:` (I've tried both.) Neither one seems to have the same effect, as the toolbar is still present after moving on, coming back, locking and unlocking.

I've even tried placing it in `viewDidAppear:` after reading through this thread [Keyboard does not disappear after viewDidDisappear on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892685/keyboard-does-not-disappear-after-viewdiddisappear-on-ios-7), but that didn't work either.

Any suggestions for why calling `endEditing:` in the lifecycle methods isn't accomplishing the same thing as calling it when the Done button is hit?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the viewWillDisappear i think if you lock the phone, you wouldnt see it fired, you would have to register for notifications of ApplicationWillEnterBackground I can add an asnwer withe the code if you need.

Comment: Hmmm, I could try registering for that notification and seeing, but the bug is triggered when you leave the view for the next screen in the flow and then come back before locking the phone, so `viewWillDisappear:` gets triggered when leaving the view, which should call `endEditing:` before I actually hit the next screen.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in to make sure its being called ?

Comment: Yeah and it is being called and hitting that line as expected, but it doesn't seem to have the same effect that calling 'endEditing:' not in a lifecycle method has. I'm wondering if 'endEditing:' isn't meant to be called in a lfiecycle method but couldn't find any documentation saying it shouldn't be.

Comment: try removing the selectedAmount and do [self.view endEditing];

Comment: Well our test environments have decided to go down right as I am attempting to try it, but I was trying for my sanity, I'm 98% I've tried self.view before and had the same defect with it. I'm suspicious that `endEditing:` isn't allowed to be called in lifecycle methods. I'm attempting to get a working environment up so I can try using the background notifications, as I think you may be on to something there.